# Socket.io-client 1.0 automatic port discovery not working

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I'm upgrading Socket.io from 0.9 to 1.0.6.

I've noticed the automatic port discovery seems to have changed in socket.io-client.  I used to be able to connect to a socket.io server like this:

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client').connect('http://localhost');
```

However, in Socket.io-client 1.0 it seems I now i have to specify a port, like

```
var socket = require('socket.io-client')('http://localhost:1337');
```

This would be OK, but Heroku assigns my socket.io server a port dynamically so I can't rely on hard-coding it.  Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that connecting to `http://yourapp.herokuapp.com:80` works, i.e. always using port 80.